# Exegesis of Galatians 4:12. Is the presented analysis valid?

Tags: galatians, pauline-epistles, metaphor

> Galatians 4:12 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> 12 I beg of you, brethren, become as I am, for I also have become as
>   you are. You have done me no wrong;
>
> Galatians 4:12 King James Version (KJV)
>
> 12 Brethren, I beseech you, be as I am; for I am as ye are: ye have
>   not injured me at all.
>
> Galatians 4:12 English Standard Version (ESV)
>
> 12 Brothers,[a] I entreat you, become as I am, for I also have become as you are. You did me no wrong.

---

**Analyzing Paul's faith in progression**

Ethnic & outwardly observant religious Jew emphasizing that obeying Jewish Laws and rituals is important

-----to------->

follower of Jesus Christ (but **not** a Judaizer (i.e. Jews who acknowledged Jesus Christ, but also emphasizing that obeying Jewish Laws and rituals is important))

**Analyzing Galatians's faith in progression**

Most likely majority Gentiles who obviously did **not** emphasize that obeying Jewish Laws and rituals is important (**I am assuming** there were **no** Jews among the Galatians)

-----to------->

follower of Jesus Christ but **manipulated** by Judaizers (i.e. Jews who acknowledged Jesus Christ, but also emphasizing that obeying Jewish Laws and rituals is important) to follow said Jewish Laws and rituals

---

Keeping the aforementioned analysis in mind, this is how I view (Galatians 4:12)

> I beg of you, brethren, become as I am

Paul is urging the Galatians to be a follower of Jesus Christ (and
**not** emphasize that obeying Jewish Laws and rituals as being important)

> for I also have become as you are

Paul is stating that he himself, by **currently not** being captive to Jewish Law and rituals became like the Gentiles since Gentiles obviously do not emphasize that obeying Jewish Laws and rituals is important

Is there something incorrect and/or missing from this view?

Answer (score 3):

The context of Galatians 4 suggests that, yes, Paul was inviting the Galatians to abandon the Mosaic Law with its precepts and ceremonies when he said "become as I am." Here is the context. Notice that only two verses earlier, Paul rebukes them for observing Mosaic "days, and months, and times, and years."

> Galatians 4:10-4:12 (DRB) **You observe days, and months, and times, and years.** I am afraid of you, lest **perhaps I have laboured in vain among you**. Be ye as I, because I also am as you: bretheren, I beseech you: you have not injured me at all.

This is also how [St. John Chyrsostom](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/23104.htm) understood Galatians 4:12. You will notice, however, that Chrysostom seems to think that there actually were some Jews among the Galatians.

> "I beseech you, brethren, be as I am; for I am as you are." 
>   This is addressed to his Jewish disciples, and he brings his own example forward, to induce them thereby to abandon their old customs. Though you had none other for a pattern, he says, to look at me only would have sufficed for such a change, and for your taking courage. Therefore gaze on me; I too was once in your state of mind, especially so; I had a burning zeal for the Law; yet afterwards I feared not to abandon the Law, to withdraw from that rule of life. And this you know full well how obstinately I clung hold of Judaism, and how with yet greater force I let it go. He does well to place this last in order: for most men, though they are given a thousand reasons, and those just ones, are more readily influenced by that which is like their own case, and more firmly hold to that which they see done by others.

---

**Q: But, how do we that Paul was rebuking them for observing the Mosaic Law and not something else?**

**A:We don't know with 100% certainty, but the context of *Galatians* strongly suggests that Paul is referring to the Mosaic Law. He talks about it A LOT, noting how it doesn't need to be followed anymore.**

- (Galatains 5:2) Behold, I Paul tell you, that **if you be circumcised, Christ shall profit you nothing.**
- (Galatians 6:12) **For as many as desire to please in the flesh, they constrain you to be circumcised**, only that they may not suffer the persecution of the cross of Christ.
- (Galatians 4:4-5) But when the fulness  of the time was come, God sent his Son, made of a woman, **made under the law: That he might redeem them who were under the law**: that we might receive the adoption of sons
- (Galatians 3:24-25) Wherefore **the law WAS our pedagogue** in Christ, that we might be justified by faith. But after the faith is come, **we are no longer under a pedagogue**.